# Change DIV background when child input field is selected

Tags: javascript, input, jquery-events

I have multiple DIV radio buttons and would like to have the background (or class) change to blue if the the child input is changed and if I select other option of the same name group, the background for the div is set back to white.

[Here is what i was hoping to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iU99q.jpg)

I have tried to use .focusin or .focusout, but the style only affects the input radio button but not the div.

For example, if I select 80s, I want to add a class or change the background to blue for that specific div only.

**SOLUTION - FIXED:**

```js
const allFormGroups = document.querySelectorAll('.questionGroup');

allFormGroups.forEach(questionGroup => {

  questionGroup.addEventListener('change', (evt) => {

    evt.currentTarget
      .querySelectorAll('.questionclass-selected')
      .forEach(element => {
        element.classList.remove('questionclass-selected')
      });

    evt.target
      .closest('.form-check')
      .classList.add('questionclass-selected');

  }, true);

});
```

```css
.questionclass {
  border-radius: var(--bs-border-radius-pill)!important;
  color: #fff!important;
  background-color: RGBA(13, 110, 253, var(--bs-bg-opacity, 1))!important;
}

.questionclass-selected {
  border-radius: var(--bs-border-radius-pill)!important;
  color: #000!important;
  background-color: RGBA(255, 193, 7, var(--bs-bg-opacity, 1))!important;
}

.active {
  color: red;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>entr-radio-buttons</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <p class="fs-2 text-primary">Hello music lover</p>
    <div class="questionGroup">
      <p>Which music genre you prefer?</p>
      <div class="form-check border rounded-pill questionclass" name="musicgenre"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="formCheck-1" name="musicgenre"><label class="form-check-label" for="formCheck-1" name="musicgenre">70s</label></div>
      <div class="form-check border rounded-pill questionclass" name="musicgenre"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="formCheck-2" name="musicgenre" selected=""><label class="form-check-label" for="formCheck-2" name="musicgenre">80s</label></div>
      <div class="form-check border rounded-pill questionclass" name="musicgenre"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="formCheck-4" name="musicgenre"><label class="form-check-label" for="formCheck-4" name="musicgenre">90s</label></div>
    </div>
    <div class="questionGroup">
      <p>What kind of music you like?</p>
      <div class="form-check border rounded-pill questionclass" name="musictype"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="formCheck-3" name="musictype"><label class="form-check-label" for="formCheck-3" name="musictype">Classical</label></div>
      <div class="form-check border rounded-pill questionclass" name="musictype"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="formCheck-5" name="musictype"><label class="form-check-label" for="formCheck-5" name="musictype">Pop</label></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/_questionToggle.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the selector :has and look for :checked radios:

```css
.form-check:has(:checked){
     background:blue;
     border-radius:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <p class="fs-2 text-primary">Hello music lover</p>
        <div id="question1">
            <p>Which music genre you prefer?</p>
            <div class="form-check" name="musicgenre"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="formCheck-1" name="musicgenre"><label class="form-check-label" for="formCheck-1" name="musicgenre">70s</label></div>
            <div class="form-check" name="musicgenre"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="formCheck-2" name="musicgenre"><label class="form-check-label" for="formCheck-2" name="musicgenre">80s</label></div>
            <div class="form-check" name="musicgenre"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="formCheck-4" name="musicgenre"><label class="form-check-label" for="formCheck-4" name="musicgenre">90s</label></div>
        </div>
        <div id="question2">
            <p>What kind of music you like?</p>
            <div class="form-check" name="musictype"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="formCheck-3" name="musictype"><label class="form-check-label" for="formCheck-3" name="musictype">Classical</label></div>
            <div class="form-check" name="musictype"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="formCheck-5" name="musictype"><label class="form-check-label" for="formCheck-5" name="musictype">Pop</label></div>
            <div class="form-check" name="musictype"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="formCheck-6" name="musictype"><label class="form-check-label" for="formCheck-6" name="musictype">Country</label></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you imvain2 for the response.  I got it to working.